# React Native image mapper (How to make touchable area on image)

Tags: react-native

How to make touchable area on image [click on position 1 show effect and same effects and different effects show on another position 2, 3, 4, 5.]

Actually when i am Clicking on Particular Position On an image, getting the Corresponding x and y co-ordinates but not getting touchable area on image

Comment: https://coldiary.github.io/react-image-mapper/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this

we have to create a mapping object similar to this

```
    const MAPPING = [
  {
    id: '0',
    name: 'First Area Name',
    shape: 'rectangle',
    width: 30,
    height: 40,
    x1: 80,
    y1: 500,
    prefill: 'red',
    fill: 'blue'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Second Area Name',
    shape: 'rectangle',
    x2: 155,
    y2: 540,
    x1: 125,
    y1: 500
  },
]
```

using of ImageMapper

```
 <ImageMapper
        imgHeight={500}
        imgWidth={250}
        imgSource={imageSource}
        imgMap={MAPPING}
        onPress={(item, idx, event) => this.onAnyAreaPress(item, idx, event)}
        containerStyle={styles.myCustomStyle}
        selectedAreaId="my_area_id"
      />
```

It provided touch points based on mappings we pass.
Please go through this doc for more info.
[Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-mapper)